# Drools - extract Map embedded inside a Map

Tags: drools

here is my data structure :

```
public class Premium{

    private Map<String,Map<String,String>> valuesMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
    
    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getValuesMap() {
       return valuesMap;
    }
}
```

Sample values that will be present inside this 'valuesMap' :

```
Map<String,String> m1= new HashMap<String,String>();
m1.put("death","100");
m1.put("income","50");

valuesMap.put("Male",m1);
valuesMap.put("Female",m2);
....
```

So where I am struggling with is how do I extract the map 'm1' embedded within 'valuesMap' for "Male" ?
Once I can do that then I can think of looking into extracting values from within 'm1'

Here is what I have tried and nothing seems to work ...

```
rule "rule#7 testing me 001 "
when
    // below line extracts 'valuesMap' from Premium object
    $pr:Premium($masterMap:valuesMap) 

    // no error but does not go into 'then' and print SOP
    //$map :Map(this["Male"]);
    //$map :Map(this["Male"] != null);
    
    // error : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    //$map : Map(this["Male"] ) from $masterMap
    
    // prints Values Map and not the embedded map for both the below attempts
    //$map : Map(this["Male"] != "") from $masterMap
    //$map : Map(this["Male"] != null ) from $masterMap
    
    // tried java way but getting error : Unable to resolve ObjectType '$masterMap.get' : [Rule name='rule#7 testing me 001 ']
    //$map :  $masterMap.get("Male");
    
    // no error but did not fire then condition and print sop 
    //$map :  Map($masterMap.get("Male"));

    // error : Unable to resolve ObjectType '$masterMap.getGet' : [Rule name='rule#7 testing me 001 ']
    //$map :  $masterMap.getGet("Male");

    //error : Unable to resolve ObjectType '$masterMap.get' : [Rule name='rule#7 testing me 001 ']
    //$map :  $masterMap.get("Male")  from $masterMap
then   
    System.out.println("rule#7 map " + $map);
end
```

Comment: Pro tip: don't use maps in Drools. Maps serialize very poorly (an empty map takes many bytes in memory) so your rules will take much more heap than they would otherwise using POJOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pr: Premium( $masterMap: valuesMap )
Map( $male: this["Male"] ) from $masterMap
```

You really should try and avoid using Maps in your rules. That nested map structure is frankly bad practice in general. In rules, Maps are extremely  non-performant -- many years ago (10+) it was s.o.p. to pass Maps into rules, but then we figured out how bad it was. ;)

Comment: Thank you , will keep this in mind and revamp as we progress , however to complete my POC was now encountering one more issue after extracting the value from the map based on above response - will ask a separate question