# Drools - extract value inside a map and assign - error : unable to resolve method using strict-mode

Tags: drools

Thanks to @roddy for his answer to my query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207787/drools-extract-map-embedded-inside-a-map)

Copy pasting from earlier to set the context :
here is my data structure :

```
public class Premium{

    private Map<String,Map<String,String>> valuesMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
    
    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getValuesMap() {
       return valuesMap;
    }
}
```

Sample values that will be present inside this 'valuesMap' :

```
Map<String,String> m1= new HashMap<String,String>();
m1.put("death","100");
m1.put("income","50");

valuesMap.put("Male",m1);
valuesMap.put("Female",m2);
....
```

Thanks to @Roddy now I can  extract the map 'm1' embedded within 'valuesMap' for "Male"

```
rule "rule#7 testing me 001 "
when
    // below line extracts 'valuesMap' from Premium object
    $pr:Premium($masterMap:valuesMap) 
    // now have a handle to the embedded map for 'Male'
    Map( $male: this["Male"] ) from $masterMap
    
    // defining an object in which I want to populate the value from map obtained for male
    $rulesResponse:RulesResponse();
then   
    System.out.println("rule#7 map " + $map);
    // this is where in below code it is failing 
    $rulesResponse.abc = $innerMap.get("income");
end
```

when I am trying to extract the string from map against key 'income' and assign it to the 'RulesResponse' object it fails with :

```
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Object.get(java.lang.String)]
[Near : {... nse.abc = $innerMap.get("income"); ....}]
```

The response object is a simple POJO with getter and setter for attribute : abc

```
public class RulesResponse {
private String abc = "";

public String getAbc() {
    return abc;
}

public void setAbc(String abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
}
```

If I try and assign a hard coded value - it works and also reflects after the rule is executed

```
// this works
$rulesResponse.abc = "hard coded value";
```

Comment: Thanks , not sure why I am unable to set the value by extracting from Map , while I can set a hard coded value and funny thing is if I simply do a SOP while extracting from map , it works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get `this["Male"]` out of the map, it's an Object, not anything typed. It's basically due to type erasure -- `Map<String, ?>`.

You can get "income" out by doing `Map( $income: this["income"]) from $male`. Of course, now $income will too also be an Object so you'll need to cast it again. Could be as simple as a `(String)$income` on the right-hand side, or a `$incomeStr: String() from $income` on the left.

```
rule "Example"
when
    $pr: Premium( $masterMap: valuesMap != null ) 
    Map( $male: this["Male"] != null ) from $masterMap
    Map( $income: this["income"] != null ) from $male

    $rulesResponse: RulesResponse()
then
    $rulesResponse.abc = (String)$income; // cast as necessary
end
```

We lose the nested type identity because of type erasure -- you've got a `Map<String, ?>` which becomes `Map<String, Object>` in practice.

---

Strongly suggest using a properly structured POJO instead of a Map as a rule input. Even if your actual code uses these nested maps (bad practice!), you should leverage a transform before calling the rules -- not only will your rules be a lot simpler and easier to work with, but they'll also be much more performant.

Even converting that inner map into an object will make things easier:

```
class GenderValues {
  String death;
  String income;
}

class Premium {
  Map<String, GenderValues> valuesByGender;
}
```

Best practice would be to omit the Map entirely.

Comment: Thank you !!! and I agree now that this POC w.r.t to existing code ( Map within Map ) is done , will look to refactor code as you have suggested . I did try yesterday something like this `$lf: (java.util.Map)(male).get("income")` . Thank you once again for your patience and help on the numerous questions , thank you

Comment: thank you for all the help . I am just curious to get your view on two queries / observations : #1 ( query ) - regarding usage of Maps in Drools as a bad practice / to be avoided - could you point me to any reference documentation please ?  #2 ( Observations ) Maybe I am new and maybe I dont learn well from reading a lot Vs actual implementation - but I did not find a lot of examples in the drools documentation , is that just me ? :)